# Django QuerySet Two-Valued Subquery

Tags: django, django-queryset

Given a model

```
class Entity(models.Model):
    identifier = models.IntegerField()
    created = models.IntegerField()
    content = models.IntegerField()

    class Meta:
        unique_together = (('identifier', 'created'))
```

I would like to query for all objects with `created` being maximal among objects with common `identifier`.

In SQL a window function in a subquery solves the problem:

```
SELECT identifier, content
  FROM entity
  WHERE (identifier, created)
    IN (SELECT identifier, max(created) OVER (PARTITION BY identifier)
          FROM entity);
```

See also: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c541f/1/0

Both window functions and subqueries are available in Django 2.0. However, I have not found a way to express subquery expressions with multiple columns.

Is there a way to translate that SQL query into the Django QuerySet world? Is this maybe a an XY problem and my problem can be solved differently?

My ugly workaround is

```
Entity.objects.raw('''
SELECT * FROM app_entity e
 WHERE e.created = (SELECT max(f.created) FROM app_entity f WHERE e.identifier = f.identifier)''')
```

since the underlying sqlite3 version apparently cannot handle multi-column subqueries.

Answer (score 3):

I think you can do it another way (but I'm not sure if it will perform better or worse than a window expression)...

```
max_created = Entity.objects.filter(
    identifier=OuterRef('identifier')
).order_by('-created').values('created')[:1]

Entity.objects.filter(
    created=Subquery(max_created)
)
```

This grabs the largest `created` value for a given `identifier`, as a correlated subquery, and then filters for only those that match.

This may need tweaking: I'm not sure if you can filter on the subquery like that, or if you need to `.annotate(max_created=Subquery(created)).filter(created=F('max_created'))`  or something else horrible like that.

Also, if you are on postgres, you can use the `DISTINCT ON` feature to get a really neat solution:

```
Entity.objects.order_by('identifier', '-created').distinct('identifier')
```

Answer (score 1):

The [Postgres specific version](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52034294/4391298) works really well but doesn't combine well with filtering that has to happen before / after the collapse. It also can't be ordered.

What I've done is use this in a subquery:

```
class LatestQuerySet(models.QuerySet):
    def latest_objects(self):
        # Get the latest version of every object matching the current query
        latest = (
            self
            # Sort by identifier with latest version first
            .order_by("identifier", "-created")
            # This only works on Postgres
            .distinct("identifier")
        )

        # Return a new queryset that includes the subquery
        return self.filter(id__in=latest)
```

This can then be combined like:

```
# Find the latest version of every object that is at least staged for publication
# and check whether that object should be published in its latest version.
Entity.objects\
    .filter(state__gte=STAGED_FOR_PUBLISH)\
    .latest_objects()\
    .filter(include_entity=True)
```

Comment: You shouldn't need to do the subquery: you can use the .distinct('identifier') directly in the QuerySet.

Comment: You can do the DISTINCT directly if you only order and filter before the DISTINCT (usually needed to ensure the correct item comes out). You cannot order and filter the remaining results. The subquery is required if you wish to do filtering/ordering after DISTINCT.

Comment: You can still filter _after_ a distinct - and indeed you can apply the ordering _after_ your .distinct: `Person.objects.distinct('company__name').order_by('company', 'pk').filter(first_name='X')`. However, you are correct in the sense that this is actually different (in some cases) to doing it as a subquery: in my case, any person that has the name 'X' will work, rather than the intended "people who were the first person at their company who have the name X".

Comment: (ie, Django will handle .filter(), .order_by() and .distinct(on) statements in any order so that it's a valid query, but it may _mean_ something different. I missed that in your example).

Comment: Yes, by before and after, I mean in the order the operations are applied, rather than the literal order in the queryset. When ordering, you can usually work around this by ordering on several columns (so long as they don't conflict), but for filtering, it can easily change the result.